# Import provided by both the main module and the vendor directory is flagged as an error

Tags: go, go-modules, govendor

I would like to understand the reason for the error I have experienced while brushing up on go modules & the vendor directory. Apparently, having the same package in the main module and the vendor folder results in an error and I would like to understand why. As far as I understand, if there is a `go.mod` `go` shouldn't even check the `vendor` folder for dependencies. Once I run `go run ./main.go` I get the following error:

```
main.go:3:8: ambiguous import: found package test/testpkg in multiple directories:
        /Users/mic4ael/dev/mine/something-in-go/testpkg
        /Users/mic4ael/dev/mine/something-in-go/vendor/test/testpkg
```

However, this doesn't happen when `go build -mod=mod` is used to build a binary. I would appreciate explanation why this is the case.

```
GO111MODULE=""
```

```
$ tree
.
├── go.mod
├── main.go
├── test
├── testpkg
│   └── lib.go
└── vendor
    └── test
        └── testpkg
            └── lib.go
```

go.mod

```golang
module test

go 1.15
```

main.go

```golang
package main

import "test/testpkg"

func main() {
    testpkg.Echo("Test")
}
```

vendor/test/testpkg/lib.go

```golang
package testpkg

import "fmt"

func Echo(str string) {
    fmt.Printf("From vendored package %s\n", str)
}
```

testpkg/lib.go

```golang
package testpkg

import "fmt"

func Echo(str string) {
    fmt.Printf("From internal pkg: %s\n", str)
}
```

Comment: I can see [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/modload/import.go#L225) why this happens but I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

There are two packages with the same name, and that is the ambiguity. When you import `test/testpkg` it can be imported from the project itself or from the vendor directory.

Using go modules does not change the vendoring behavior. In fact, you can use `go mod vendor` to vendor modules locally. If a package appears under `vendor/` it will be used from the vendored copy, otherwise it will be downloaded and used from the module cache. However, if you have a package in your project with the identical name as one of the packages under vendor, there is an ambiguity.

Comment: I understand where the ambiguity comes from, however in module-aware context, shouldn't `go` just skip the vendor folder?

Comment: It doesn't. You can still vendor external dependencies.

Comment: I still don't understand why running `go build -mod=mod` doesn't have the same problem. What does `-mod=mod` change?

Comment: Ok, nvm, I found my answer in `go help modules`